# Accessing Information from a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( [0] => id [1] => 4 )
Array ( [0] => first_name [1] => F_NAME )
Array ( [0] => last_name [1] => L_NAME )
Array ( [0] => email [1] => EMAIL )
```

Hey,

I'm wondering how I can create a variable named after the type of information stored that stores the actual information. For example, there are 4 pieces of data in the above array. I'd like to have:

```
$id = 4;
$first_name = 'F_NAME';
$last_name = 'L_NAME';
$email = 'EMAIL';
```

I know I can use a double $ to create a variable with the name of another variable but don't know how to access the data with this array structure. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
$a = array(
  array('id', '4'), array('first_name', 'F_NAME'), // ...
);

foreach ($a as $b)
{
  $$b[0] = $b[1];
}
```

But this is a very ugly thing to do, and I'd recommend rethinking the higher strategy a bit.

Comment: See mailo's answer for a better way to store and access this kind of data (associated arrays).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php),but only in case when **id=>4** association is in array, not what you have now.

```
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

echo "$color, $size, $shape, $wddx_size\n";
```

But I think that proper approach would be to modify a little your array and use it like: `$data['first_name']`, though - interesting question.

Comment: That's true, but he could iterate over array to make it 1-D for extract(), anyways I provided a better solution suggestion.